# python 2.7 using tkinter -all checkbox are being checked when click on one only

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I'm using python 2.7 with Tkinter (new to Tkinter:))
I have UI with list of 20 checkboxes
once I click on one checkbox, all checkboxes are being checked, instead of one.
In code below you'll see 2 line (once with #)
with # -when click on checkbox only one is checked which is ok
without # -when click on one, all are being checked
The problem is that I want to know the status of each checkbox if checed or not and I have to define var=Intvar in order to "get" it status
Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance
Below is relevant def

```
def suites_checkbox_create(self):
    ExcelWorkBook1 = open_workbook(config.UI_Suites_Location + 'STD_SUITES.xlsx', on_demand=True)
    First_Sheet1 = ExcelWorkBook1.sheet_by_index(0)
    plushight = 110
    suitesList=[]
    self.CheckboxList=[]
    for name in (First_Sheet1._cell_values):
        if name[3] == "General Name":
            continue
        else:
            suitesList.append(name[3])


    for index, name in enumerate(suitesList):

            self.var=IntVar
            #self.CheckboxList.append(Checkbutton(self.app, text=name)) # using this, i can check once checkbox a time
            self.CheckboxList.append(Checkbutton(self.app, text=name, variable=self.var)) # with this, once i check once checkbox, all checkboxes(20) are bing checked
            self.CheckboxList[index].place(y=plushight)
            plushight += 20
```

Comment: You have forgotten the brackets for `IntVar` and if you want to be able to get the state of each checkbutton, you need to put the IntVars in a list like for the checkbuttons.

Answer (score 3):

The reason this happens is because you've given all of your `Checkbutton` widgets the same variable for their `variable` attribute.

Meaning that as soon as one of the `Checkbutton` widgets is ticked `self.var` is given a value of `1` which means that all of the `Checkbutton` widgets have a value of `1` which equates to them having been selected.

In short, whenever one is ticked it updates the value of all the other's because they have the same variable used to store their value.

See this in the example below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
var = IntVar()

for i in range(10):
    Checkbutton(root, text="Option "+str(i), variable = var).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

To resolve this you need to use a different variable for each `Checkbutton`, like the below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
var = []

for i in range(10):
    var.append(IntVar())
    Checkbutton(root, text="Option "+str(i), variable = var[i]).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You will also have this same issue if your Variables are not set to be an IntVar(). You must assign them to be IntVars like so: checkboxvar = IntVar(). Also note that to get the value of the checkbox, you must do checkboxvar.get()