# Tkinter problem: checking one checkbox checks all of them

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm writing a little program that needs the user to decide some boolean values. I've made checkboxes to handle this part, but the problem is that every time I check or uncheck one, all the others follow along.

I've searched online, but the only explanation I found ([python 2.7 using tkinter -all checkbox are being checked when click on one only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46927271/python-2-7-using-tkinter-all-checkbox-are-being-checked-when-click-on-one-only)) doesn't seem to apply in my case.

```
import tkinter as tk

''' Init '''
variable1 = True
variable2 = True
variable3 = True

''' Set window '''
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Title')
window.geometry('600x400')

''' Contents '''
check1 = tk.Checkbutton(window, text="Sometext_1", variable=variable1, onvalue=True, offvalue=False, height=2)
check2 = tk.Checkbutton(window, text="Sometext_2", variable=variable2, onvalue=True, offvalue=False, height=2)
check3 = tk.Checkbutton(window, text="Sometext_3", variable=variable3, onvalue=True, offvalue=False, height=2)

''' Show '''
check1.pack()
check2.pack()
check3.pack()


''' Window loop '''
window.mainloop()
```

Seems like the checkboxes should be checked independently, instead they all check and uncheck as one. Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of the `variable` attribute must be instances of one of the special tkinter variables `StringVar`, `Intvar`, `DoubleVar`, or `BooleanVar`.

```
variable1 = tk.BooleanVar(value=True)
variable2 = tk.BooleanVar(value=True)
variable3 = tk.BooleanVar(value=True)
```

Note: you can only create these variables *after* creating the root window.

Comment: Thank you! I can't upvote your answer yet, but it's deeply appreciated!